# How can optimization be used as a solver?

Tags: r, optimization

In a question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) ([How to simulate censored data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159080/how-to-simulate-censored-data)), I saw that the `optim` function was used as a kind of solver instead of as an optimizer. Here is an example:

> ```r
> optim(1, fn=function(scl){(pweibull(.88, shape=.5, scale=scl, lower.tail=F)-.15)^2})
> # $par
> # [1] 0.2445312
> # ...
> pweibull(.88, shape=.5, scale=0.2445312, lower.tail=F)
> # [1] 0.1500135
> ```

I have found a tutorial on `optim` [here](http://www.magesblog.com/2013/03/how-to-use-optim-in-r.html), but I am still not able to figure out how to use `optim` to work as a solver.  I have several questions:

1. What is first parameter (i.e., the value `1` being passed in)?
2. What is the function that is passed in?
3. I can understand that it is taking the Weibull probability distribution and subtracting 0.15, but why are we squaring the result?

Comment: From ?Optim in R: The first call to the optim function is the start guess for "x". I.e. Telling the "solver" where to start from.

Comment: Hi Repmat, Thanks for that. I have done optimization, such as Newtons method and one has to use a starting value. But in the original post, the person used values of 0.5 in one Optim function and used a value of 1 in another Optim function, which seem are the same values for the scale parameter and shape parameter of the Weibull distribution being used in the question. So that is one reason why I was confused. I wonder if this is a by chance situation that he used starting values that were the same as the scale and shape parameters?

Comment: Even if you set the start value as 10 or 100 you still the right solution - but with a couple of errors. I think it is nothing more than a coincidence.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. But why he constructed the function so that is it squared is a mystery to me,

Comment: It is actually a clever adaption of the least squares method. The OP wanted to know how to find the shape parameter, when the censor rate is 0.15. This is why he subtracts 0.15. Next; Optim (in R) tries to minimize the function, so in effects he tells R to minize the (square) of the difference between: pweibull(paramaters) - 0.15

Comment: Although this question is asked in terms of R code, the real issues are understanding how optimization is used to solve for parameters. IMO it should be considered on topic here.

Comment: Hi Gung, I believe you are the original person that provided this solution method. YES, you are correct " optimization is used to solve for parameters". I have done a lot of math in University, from calculus, vector calculus, complex analysis, numerical analysis, ODE & PDE, etc, but  I have never seen this way of using  optimization to solve for parameters and applying it in the world of statistics. I want to give you GREAT PRAISE for this way of solving equations.

Comment: Hi Gung, I would really appreciate if you could enlighten us on how you are able to use optimization  to solve for parameters. Appreciate your input greatly!

Comment: @Palu, for me to be notified of your comments, you need to put the "@" symbol before my name. As it happens, I am working on an answer below, so I have seen them. Note that there was a mistake in my linked answer, which I have now corrected, although I don't think it affects your question. I need to run now, but I'll try to finish my answer later today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to my answer.  Let's walk through a few points:

- The OP (of that question) wanted to generate (pseudo-)random data from a Weibull distribution with specified shape and scale parameters, and where the censoring would be applied for all data past a certain censoring time, and end up with a prespecified censoring rate.  The problem is that once you have specified any three of those, the fourth is necessarily fixed.  You cannot specify all four simultaneously unless you are very lucky and the values you specify happen to fit together perfectly.  As it happened, the OP was not so lucky with the four preferred values—it was impossible to have all four as they were inconsistent.  At that point, you can decide to specify any three and solve for the last.  The code I presented were examples of how to do that.
- As noted in the documentation for [?optim](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html), the first argument is `par` "[i]nitial values for the parameters to be optimized over".

  Very loosely, the way the optimization routine works is that it calculates an output value given a function and an input value.  Then it 'looks around' to see if moving to a different input value would lead to a better output value.  If that appears to be the case, it moves in that direction and starts the process again.  (It stops when it does not appear that moving in either direction will yield a better output value.)

  The point is that is has to start somewhere, and the user is obliged to specify that value.  In each case, I started with the OP's preferred value (although really I could have started most anywhere).
- The function that I passed in is [?pweibull](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Weibull.html).  It is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) of the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).  It takes a quantile (**X** value) as its input and returns the proportion of the distribution that has been passed through up to that point.  Because the OP wanted to censor the most extreme 15% of that distribution, I specified that `pweibull` return the proportion that *had not yet been passed through* instead (that is the `lower.tail=F` part).  I then subtracted`.15` from the result.
- Thus, the ideal output (from my point of view) would be **0**.  However, it is possible to get values below zero by finding a scale parameter that makes the output of `pweibull` < .15.  Since `optim` (or really most any optimizer) finds the input value that minimizes the output value, that is what it would have done.  To keep that from happening, I squared the difference.  That means that when the optimizer went 'too far' and found a scale parameter that yielded an output of `.05` from `pweibull`, and the difference was `-.10` (i.e., **< 0**), the squaring makes the ultimate output `+.01` (i.e., **> 0**, or worse).  This would push the optimizer back towards the scale parameter that makes `pweibull` output **(`.15`-.15)^2 = 0**.
- In general, the distinction you are making between an "optimizer" and a "solver" is opaque to me.  They seem like [two different views of the same elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant).
- Another possible confusion here involves optimization vs. regression.  [Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) is simply about finding an input value[s] that minimizes (maximizes) the output of a function.  In [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), we conceptualize data as draws from a data generating process that is a [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic) function.  Given a set of realized values and a functional form, we use optimization techniques to estimate the parameters of the function, thus extracting the data generating process from noisy instances.  Part of regression analyses partakes of optimization then, but other aspects of regression are less concerned with optimization and optimization itself is much larger than regression.  For example, the functions optimized in my answer to the other question are deterministic, and there were no "data" being analyzed.

Comment: Thanks so much Gung for so much. I found documentation that I recall says that pweibull is the PDF(probability distribution function). I have background in statistics, I have used the Weibull distribution in Reliability analysis in the field of quality-6sigma statistics. Since by having put in one parameter of the 2 types in weibull, for the PDF weibull, one will have a non-linear equation to solve. If we are forming a least squares model and using optimization routine, don't we need to have a linear equation(i am thinking about least squares linear regression).

Comment: Does least  squares algorithm apply to non-linear functions? Excuse my ignorance, but I have only seen least square applied in linear regression to solve for parameters.

Comment: Non linear least squares is very common.

Comment: OK, thanks Repmat. Now this makes more sense to me. Because of this, I now can sleep at night. Thanks so much Repmat!!!!

Comment: @Palu, `pweibull` is not the PDF (`dweibull` is). Instead, `pweibull` is the *CDF*. On a different topic, although finding regression parameters (betas) is also optimization, what I am doing here is not regression. The optimization algorithms that `optim` calls are general purpose search algorithms. They are often used to find betas for models that don't have a closed form solution (linear regression does have a closed form solution), but they don't have to be. Finding betas is a only particular application of optimization (think all dogs are mammals, but not all mammals are dogs).

Comment: Hi Gung, I have a link >http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Weibull.html. The documentation uses slightly different terminology: Density(dwei), distribution function(pwei), quantile function(qwei) and random generation(rwei). SO they are not  using the PDF and CDF terminology.

Comment: @Palu, that is the same page I linked to above. `pweibull` is the CDF / cumulative distribution function (they call it the "distribution function"), & `dweibull` is the [PDF / probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (they call it "Density"). There is no such thing as the 'probability distribution function'.

Comment: OK, I did not notice your link above. Thanks for pointing that out. And yes I see that you are correct. I have become accustomed to call PDF the probability distribution function instead of probability density function. You are correct on the description of the functions!

Comment: Thanks once again Gung for the detailed explanation above. Really appreciate it!!!!